# Where did the cone radius parameters go in Blender 3.5

Tags: modeling

I'm a relative noob who wants to create a truncated cone. This should be real easy according to every answer I've seen, just set the radius 1 and radius 2 accordingly but in Blender 3.5 I can't find these settings. All the sample pictures are from 2.8 or similar (and they don't match 3.5 reality). Even the Blender manual is vague to be point of useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you add an object in Blender but before you carry out **any** other activity, you'll see an operator panel in the bottom-left corner of the 3D viewport. This may be collapsed so that it just shows a single line and you can expand it by clicking the down-arrow. The image below shows it when expanded.
[image]

Once you carry out any action such as Move, Scale, Rotate, etc. on the object that dialog will disappear and you can't then get it back. However, if you've just clicked in a blank part of the 3D view and done nothing else, you can use <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring back the dialog at the cursor position.

[image]

That dialog is used from version 2.83 onward by the way.

Comment: Thanks. The window was minimised, so I didn't see it.